# Command Error: Argument not optional

Tags: excel, vba

First post here on stack overflow. I'm not a coder by any means but an accountant trying to automate some tasks.

Here is a code that is continual giving me the compile error, that argument is not optional. I've seen other questions with the same title but I am not able to apply to knowledge.

Can anyone assist me in fixing this error? It would be greatly appreciated. Please & thank you in advance.

Here is the code below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:= _
   "File Location on Cloud" 
    , Type:=xlExcelLinks
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Something else i should include; the 3rd line appears in red.

Comment: Missing `_` line continuation after `"File Location on Cloud"` ?

Comment: Actually, that is available in the original code. Sorry I couldn't include the original code for privacy / confidentiality purposes.

Comment: You can't close the activewindow if it's the only window excel has - you need to  quit the application to close the last excel window

Answer (score 0):

You could combine  **ActiveWorkbook.Save** and **ActiveWindow.Close** into the single call **ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)** or **ThisWorkbook.Close(True)**. If the line **ActiveWindow.Close** is in red that is where the problem is but difficult to say w/o any context.